# Laravel - Secure Shared Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a series of Laravel apps that I want to integrate the users for, and have a single signin, so you could have safety.mywebsite.com, accounts.mywebsite.com and hr.mywebsite.com all use auth.mywebsite.com as the Auth system.

Only the auth app has a users domain, and permissions/roles are stored in individual apps (so safety, accounts and hr in the example).

I'm using Laravel Passport for the auth app, which has a login function.

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            // User is authenticated
            $user = auth()->user();

            // Create a JWT with the user data
            $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

            $returnUrl = $request->input('return_url');
            $allowedReturnUrls = config('authserver.allowed_return_urls');

            if (!in_array($returnUrl, $allowedReturnUrls, true)) {
                return response('Invalid return URL - '.$returnUrl, 400);
            }

            // Append the JWT as a query parameter
            $returnUrl .= '?token=' . $token;

            // Redirect back to the child app with the JWT
            return redirect($returnUrl);
        } else {
            // Authentication failed
            return back()->withErrors([
                'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
            ]);
        }
    }
```

And in the individual websites that JWT is captured by the callback URL.

```
    public function handleAuthServerCallback(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            // Validate and decode the JWT
            $token = $request->get('token');
            $decodedToken = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->getPayload();

            // Get user data from the token
            $userData = [
                'id' => $decodedToken['sub'],
                'name' => $decodedToken['name'],
                'email' => $decodedToken['email'],
            ];

            // Store the user data in the session
            session(['user' => $userData]);

            // Redirect to a protected route or dashboard
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle invalid token (log it, show an error message, etc.)
            Log::error('Invalid token in handleAuthServerCallback: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }
```

Finally, in the individual website, I use middleware to dummy up the Auth facade and check that the user is logged in. Obviously there are other permissions and gates, but I'm only concerned with Authentication at the moment.

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (!$request->session()->has('user')) {
            return redirect('/login/redirect');
        }

        // Get user data from session
        $userData = $request->session()->get('user');

        // Create a temporary user instance
        $user = new User($userData);
        $user->id = $userData['id'];

        // Set the temporary user as the authenticated user for this request
        Auth::setUser($user);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

I've followed the Laravel Passport carefully, I'm whitelisting return URLs using `config('authserver.allowed_return_urls')` using JWT's to move the actual data across the websites, and keeping permissions/roles on the individual sites.

It just seems that I'm missing something. I've never done this before, always used Laravel's standard inbuilt Auth system. Is this a secure way of doing this?

Comment: I think, you need to utilize laravel socialite in local sites to work with central auth server